# Is it possible to send event markers via Emotiv epoc using Inquisit 5?

Tags: eeg

I am trying to employ Emotiv for my research project. Emotiv is a mobile EEG instrument (click [here](https://www.emotiv.com/) to see more)  Unlike other EEG recording systems, I am not able to send a marker to the EEG recording using TestBench. [Although the manual](http://www.crossroadsacademy.org/crossroads/wp-content/uploads/2016//05/Test-Bench-Manual-.pdf) of Testbench has suggested the use of serial port / COM port to send **marker**, but I have failed to use serial port to do so.

I have coded my paradigm using Inquisit 5, I can send marker via a different system (Labchart) via parallel ports.

I am not sure if the serial port could actually be used and set marker at designated time. For that reason, I am just wondering if it is possible to include markers during EEG recording using Emotiv.

Comment: What do you mean by "marker system"?

Comment: Hi Seanny123, Sorry I haven't explained clearly in the original question. For other EEG recording system, they usually come with a function to send marker via parallel ports. However, I am not sure if Emotiv include the 'marker' function, in order to send out marker at designated time. I am just wondering if it is possible to include markers during EEG recording using emotiv.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include these details?